# debmirror gives error

Tags: debian, rsync, debmirror

I Use an AlmaLinux 9.3 Server to host a AlmaLinux Repo and want to add a Debian 12 Repo to the webhosted files. Therefor I use debmirror on the repo machines to mirror a debian 12 repo for local use.

```
debmirror --i18n --dist=bookworm --no-check-gpg --exclude-deb-section=games --exclude-deb-section=debug --exclude-deb-section=news --verbose --method=ftp --arch=amd64,i386 --section=main,non-free-firmware --host=ftp.debian.org /var/www/html/debian
```

During the run I get this output:

```
Arches: i386,amd64,i386
Dists: sid,bookworm
Sections: main,main/debian-installer,contrib,non-free,non-free-firmware,main,non-free-firmware
Including source.
Pdiff mode: use
Not checking Release gpg signatures.
Will clean up after mirroring.
Dry run.
Attempting to get lock ...
Updating remote trace files (using rsync) ...
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to ftp.debian.org (199.232.150.132): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: [Receiver] failed to connect to ftp.debian.org (2a04:4e42:65::644): Network is unreachable (101)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(138) [Receiver=3.2.3]
Warning: failed to use rsync to download extra files.
Getting meta files ...
[  0%] Getting: dists/bookworm/Release... ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/bookworm/InRelease... ok
[  0%] Getting: dists/bookworm/Release.gpg... ok
[GNUPG:] ERROR add_keyblock_resource 33554433
[GNUPG:] NEWSIG
[GNUPG:] ERROR keydb_search 33554445
[GNUPG:] ERROR keydb_search 33554445
//
//
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
gpgv: Signature made Sat Oct  7 11:38:14 2023 CEST
gpgv:                using EDDSA key 
4D64FEC119C2029067D6E791F8D2585B8783D481
gpgv: Can't check signature: No public key
.temp/.tmp/dists/bookworm/InRelease signature does not verify.
Errors:
 .temp/.tmp/dists/bookworm/Release.gpg signature does not verify
 .temp/.tmp/dists/bookworm/InRelease signature does not verify
Failed to download some Release, Release.gpg or InRelease files!
releasing 1 pending lock... at 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/LockFile/Simple.pm line 206.
```

I viewed the FW rules over the shoulders of our security team and SSH FTP HTTP HTTPS and port 873 (rsync deamon access) are open and allowed outbound.
I imported the keyring gpg files from the debian12.2 DVD as this debmirror is running on an AlmaLinux server where the debmirror package can be easily installed on.

What can it be that it cannot sync it's internet mirror to rsync..?

Thanks a lot for taking a look.